# How to do a rolling Groupby using a Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, grouping

I have a multi index series.  One of the indices is day and I try to go through and get the data in a day range.  I have looked into using just rolling with a time given as a string, but it returns a list of the same length whereas I only need 1 response per unique date index.

This is my current code, is there a simpler way to do this:

```
result = {}
for date in df.index.levels[2]: #this goes through all of the days
    pre_date = date - np.timedelta64(window,'D') #find window days ago
    cur_df = df.loc[idx[:,:,pre_dat:date],:] #get all data in that window day range
    result[date] = f(cur_df)
result = pd.Series(result)
```

Comment: Looking at it now, it seems that the fact that this is a multiIndex is irrelivant other than the fact that the Date level of the Index has multiple, entries of the same date